# How to use jQuery in a cloud9 plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloud9-ide

I am currently writing a Cloud9 plugin and would like to use jQuery to retrieve some JSON data from a remote server. However, I don't know how to go about it. Is it even possible to use jQuery in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to not use jquery in the ide, and use http service instead.
add http to imports of your plugin and then call `http.request(url, options, callback)`

Comment: How do I import http? Just use `var http = require("http")`? In this case, my plugin does not get loaded anymore.

Comment: add it to consumes array, and then use imports.http see https://github.com/c9/core/blob/0e5f9df9a00e4e4d8e87eb73dac9e7379b7977e4/plugins/c9.cli/auth.bootstrap.js#L1-L8